# How to store client id and secret in html/js clients for OAuth 2.0

Tags: security, oauth-2.0

I recently implemented OUTH 2.0 (with [tastypie](https://django-tastypie.readthedocs.org/en/latest/)) to my APIs. Now I am building an [emberjs](http://emberjs.com/) based JS client. How can I store my client ID and Client Secret securely? Local storage I would assume doesn't help, since a user can just retrieve client ID and secret pretty easily. The same applies for cookie storage. I've been trying to research the best practices for awhile but I cannot find anything anywhere. Any thoughts on how others have tackled this issue? Any resources will be much appreciated.

Comment: Script client are [public clients](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc6749#section-2.1) and are not supposed to have credentials. Your client ID is [a public information](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc6749#section-2.2), so you do not need to keep it secured.

Comment: https://developers.google.com/accounts/docs/OAuth2UserAgent